# Nested Recyclerview ( recyclerview inner recyclerview ) how to optimize? scrolling, performance issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

i have struggled with this [nested recyclerview] problems.

The biggest issue about this is performance.

When i scrolling down or upside, annoying laggy is occur.

I found some advice that [using expandable recyclerview, rather than using nested recyclerview] but, i cannot adjust it to mycase.

i'll attach my structure, and some code of mine.

Would you check it and give me some nice tips? Thx in advance.

- 1> This is my list item structure.
  Recyclerview with CardView item and each cardView has list item. its length is variable, so i made it by recyclerview.

[image: RECYCLERVIEW STRUCTURE]

- 2> This is my code.
- Code in ViewHolder

  ```
  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  ...
      ImageView issueImg;
      RecyclerView issue_poll_detail_list;
  ...
      RelativeLayout commentLayout;
      TextView commentTxt;
  ...

  public ViewHolder(View view) {
      super(view);

      issueImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.issue_card_img);

      issue_poll_detail_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.issue_poll_detail_list);
      issue_poll_detail_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
      issue_poll_detail_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
      issue_poll_detail_list.setFocusable(false);

      issue_poll_detail_list.setDescendant...(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
      issue_poll_detail_list.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

      ...
      commentLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.issue_poll_footer_reply);
      commentTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.issue_poll_footer_reply_txt);

      ...
  ```

&
* Code in Adapter

```
    holder.issue_poll_detail_list.setLayoutManager(new WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(context));
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) holder.issue_poll_detail_list.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

    pollAdapter = new PollAdapter(context, glideRequestManager, issuePolls.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()), issuePolls.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getNumAnswer(),
            issuePolls.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCalcStartTime(), issuePolls.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCalcEndTime());


    holder.issue_poll_detail_list.setAdapter(pollAdapter);
```

Thx !!!